# How to export a python list to a csv and add line breaks

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a python list and I would like to export it to a csv file, but I don't want to store all the list in the same row. I would like to slice the list at a given point and start a new line. Something like this:

```
list = [x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4]
```

and I would like it to export it in this format

```
 x1 x2 x3 x4
 y1 y2 y3 y4
```

So far I have this:

```
import csv
A = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
result = open("newfile.csv",'wb')
writer = csv.writer(result, dialect = 'excel')
writer.writerow(A)
result.close
```

And the output looks something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I would like the output to be

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
```

Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `list` (call it `seq`) and a target row length (call it `rowsize`), you would do something like this:

```
split_into_rows = [seq[i: i + rowsize] for i in range(0, len(seq), rowsize)]
```

You could then use the writer's `writerows` method to write elements to the file:

```
writer.writerows(split_into_rows)
```

For lazy evaluation, use a generator expression instead:

```
split_into_rows = (seq[i: i + rowsize] for i in range(0, len(seq), rowsize))
```

Comment: Or chuck the intermediate list and pass as a generator expression directly to `writerows`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Point taken. I think it's better for the purposes of illustration to separate the steps though.

Comment: Correction: You can't use `islice()` because `csv.writer.writerows()` can only handle rows which are sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a temp array B.

1. Get the length of the original array A
2. Copy the first A.length/2 to array B
3. Add new line character to array B.
4. Append the rest of array A to B.

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with lists in this manner, it's best to use the numpy module:

```
import numpy as np
A = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
#now to convert your list into a 2-Dimensional numpy array
A = np.array((A)).reshape((2,4))
result = open("newfile.csv",'wb')
writer = csv.writer(result, dialect = 'excel')
#you use writer.writerows() instead of .writerow because you have multiple rows rather than one
writer.writerows(row)
result.close
```

numpy provides many ways of manipulating lists. Look at some documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/)

Yes there are many ways to do what you want, but you'll have to deal with lists that are not just simply equivalent to `range(1,9)` and with numpy you can not only concisely do what you want to do, you can manipulate your list in many many different ways once you convert it to a numpy array

Comment: You can use `writer.writerows()` to avoid the explicit `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import csv
>>> A = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
>>> with open("newfile.csv",'wb') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerows(zip(*[iter(A)]*4))
```

Comment: When I run this, I get the following as an error:
*TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface*

Answer (score -1):

This

```
import itertools
l = ['a1','a2','b1','b2']

def toCSV(fname,l):
    with open(fname+'.csv','w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join([','.join(list(g)) for k,g in itertools.groupby(l,key=lambda k: k[0])]))


toCSV('mycsv',l)
```

Would yield

```
a1,a2
b1,b2
```

It relies heavily on itertool's groupby function. [Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).Essentially it will group the element based on a key. The key can be calculated using a lambda expression, which in this case would be the algebraic letter before the number.

Comment: I don't think there is a particularly good reason to _not_ use the `csv` module when dealing with CSV data.

Comment: Nor in this case a particularly good reason *to* use the csv module

Comment: Using the `csv` module for csv files effectively communicates the intent of the programmer, as well as standardizing the csv formatting. Notice that the OP selected `dialect="excel"` rather than worry about whether to use `\r\n` or `\n` as a line-terminator, which `quotechar` to use, etc...